# how is configured ibm websphere mq architecture

Tags: ibm-mq

I need to know how IBM Websphere MQ works.

As of my knowledge.

1. IBM Websphere MQ is an application that runs continuously
2. IBM Websphere MQ has a queue manager, queue name, port, host where it is runs, channel name.
3. We have a two different application in two different remote place.
4. Two applications and the IBM Websphere MQ applications are connected through network.
5. Using IBM Websphere MQ credentials the applications are able to send and receive messages between them via IBM Websphere MQ.

If I have anything wrong then please guide me.

My questions are:

1. If one application sends a message to the queue then where will the memory be consumed?
2. Where do we run the MQ listeners?  On the applications environment or the Websphere environment (where we installed the IBM Websphere MQ)?
3. Do we need to run any programs in the application environments or are the IBM Websphere MQ credentials (queue manager, queue name, port, host where it is runs, channel name) enough to send and receive the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one application sends a message to the queue then where will the memory be consumed?

A Running Queue Manager requires memory in order to run and handle processing/storage of messages. As well as that every MQ Client application that connects to a Queue Manager requires memory to connect to and put/get messages. This is no different than any application that runs on any system.

> Where do we run the MQ listeners?

Assuming you mean MQ Listeners. The MQ Listeners are run on the Queue Manager and specify the (TCP) port you want the Queue Manager to listen on.

> Do we need to run any programs in the application environments or are the IBM Websphere MQ credentials (queue manager, queue name, port, host where it is runs, channel name) enough to send and receive the messages?

To run a Queue Manager on a machine, your machine must meet the System requirements stated in the `System Requirements for WebSphere MQ` page. 
[Here is the MQ v8 one](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27041395)

Likewise to run a MQ Client application that can connect into a Queue Manager, the application needs to have be ran on a machine that has the IBM MQ Client libraries installed on and meet the system requirements.

You also need to tell the application:

- The location of the Queue Manager hostname/IP Address and port number.
- The channel to connect into, which must exist on the Queue Manager
- The Queue name to interact with, which must exist on the Queue Manager

Depending on your Queue Manager's configuration you need to ensure that your application is running with the correct user/supplying the correct user to ensure it is properly authorized to access the Queue Manager.

Comment: Hi @fresher Was my answer able to help you or was something missing?

Comment: thanks @rob parker. it was so helpful to understand the setup.

Comment: Hi @Fresher If my answer was helpful and solved your problem could you consider accepting my answer? See here for more tips on what do to when someone answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi @Rob is there any way to pause the queue in the middle of reading the messages from queue. 
for example  my application was designed to keep on reading the messages from the queue. i want to pause the queue for sometime . in that time my application need to run and try to read the messages from the queue but queue should not provide any messages since I have a paused the queue.  is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: A queue just holds messages, if you want an application to stop putting/getting messages to a queue for a while then you need to do it in the application. If you want the Queue to not even be able to receive messages you can inhibit the queue to stop it from being able to have messages put to it but then your applications will receive a non-zero return code from MQ. Which, unless your application can handle, will cause them to fail.

Comment: then that is not an issue, I will design the app to handle it. 
I need to stop the queue because after the product completion, i only have the access for the receiver queues, currently I have 3 different queues which is used by three different app. I have below queries please guide me.
1. so if i stop the one of the queue at the time when other 2 queues  are in running then any thing happen (like message purge).
2. if i pause the receiver queue , is that have any impact on message sending application.
3. kindly provide the command for pause the queue if we have ?

Comment: 1. Queues do not run, they just sit there and applications put/get from them.
2. See answer to 1. What happens to a Queue depends on what applications are interacting with Queues
3. I believe the attribute `PUT` and `GET` on the queue objects is what you are looking for. If you set these to `DISABLED` then an application will not be able to perform that action on the Queue. So if you set `PUT` to `DISABLED` then that Queue will empty as long as an application is emptying the queue.

Note: Things might be slightly different with remote/alias/cluster queues.